# How can I receive messages to a C# Console app from an Azure IoT Hub device, using the Azure IoT Hub SDK

Tags: c#, azure, azure-iot-hub

I am currently writing logic to test receiving data from an Azure IoT hub device into my console app. I've got the IoT Hub connected to a container so I can see messages entering the container, but not in the console app. I've checked that the console app is successfully connected to the hub, and that dummy messages can be sent to the device, but they can't be received

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;


namespace IoTHubTesting2
{
    class Program
    {
        private static DeviceClient _deviceClient;
        private static string _connectionString = "ConnectionString";
        private static string deviceID = ("TestDevice1");

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Connecting to Azure IoT Hub...");
            _deviceClient = DeviceClient.CreateFromConnectionString(_connectionString, TransportType.Amqp);

            try
            {
                _deviceClient.OpenAsync().Wait();
                Console.WriteLine("Successfully connected to Azure IoT Hub.");
                SendSimulatedMessage();
                ReceiveMessages();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Failed to connect to Azure IoT Hub.");
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static async void ReceiveMessages()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Listening for messages from Azure IoT Hub...");
            while (true)
            {
                var message = await _deviceClient.ReceiveAsync();
                if (message == null) continue;
                var messageString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message.GetBytes());
                Console.WriteLine("Received message: {0}", messageString);

                // Parse message as JSON
                var messageData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(messageString);
                Console.WriteLine("Message data: {0}", messageData);

                await _deviceClient.CompleteAsync(message);
            }
        }

        private static async void SendSimulatedMessage()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Sending a simulated message to Azure IoT Hub...");
            var message = new Message(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hello from the console app!"));
            await _deviceClient.SendEventAsync(message);
            Console.WriteLine("Simulated message sent.");
        }
    }
}
```

Can't receive any messages at all

Answer (score 1):

I Followed the below steps to connect the IoT Hub and I can see messages sent to device in console application.

- Create a IoT Hub

[image]

- Go to the IoT hub you created. Search for Devices and add device.

[image]

- Create Device by giving the  device name and click on Save.

[image]

- In Visual Studio select Console application and enter this code

```cs
using System;
using Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client;
using System.Text;

namespace IoTHubReceiver
{
    class Program
    {
        private static DeviceClient _deviceClient;
        private static string _connectionString = "[Your Device connection String](https://i.imgur.com/KFP47V8.png)  ";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Connecting to Azure IoT Hub...");
            _deviceClient = DeviceClient.CreateFromConnectionString(_connectionString, TransportType.Amqp);

            try
            {
                _deviceClient.OpenAsync().Wait();
                Console.WriteLine("Successfully connected to Azure IoT Hub.");
                ReceiveMessages();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Failed to connect to Azure IoT Hub.");
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static async void ReceiveMessages()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Listening for messages from Azure IoT Hub...");
            while (true)
            {
                var message = await _deviceClient.ReceiveAsync();
                if (message == null) continue;
                var messageString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message.GetBytes());
                Console.WriteLine("Received message: {0}", messageString);
                await _deviceClient.CompleteAsync(message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

- Run the console application and check device is connected or not.

[image]

- Go to IoT device you created click on [Message to Device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ldTD7.png)  .Type you message and click on send .

[image]

- Check the Run window of Console application to check the message.

[image]

Comment: That works. However, I have the device receiving messages from a device over MQTT, and I can't see them in the console? Any ideas? I can see the messages arrive as I have a container hooked up as an endpoint for the IoT Hub, but wouldn't the messages arrive in the console app too?

Comment: Did you get a chance to look into the [Cumulocity IoT Guides.](https://cumulocity.com/guides/10.6.0/device-sdk/mqtt-examples/#hello-mqtt-cs)